# libssh2 - read file with SFTP

Tags: c++, string, sftp, libssh2

I'm using libssh2 lib to make SFTP session with the device.

But when I try to read a file and return the output, never return the complete file.

I think is because control chars (like `\0`) in the middle of the file.

Code:

```
sftp_handle = libssh2_sftp_open(sftp_session, filename, LIBSSH2_FXF_READ, 0);
if (!sftp_handle) return "-1";
char buf[99999];
int x = libssh2_sftp_read(sftp_handle, buf, sizeof(buf));
char * output = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*x);
memcpy(output, buf, x);
output[x] = '\0';
libssh2_sftp_close(sftp_handle);
```

************Update 1************

The file I'm trying to read is a text file with almost all the ascii chars.

************Update 2************

`x` is the number of bytes writen into the buffer and the file have ~98kb (99999 bytes) but the `libssh2_sftp_read` function return 30000 to `x`.

Comment: Have you checked what `libssh2_sftp_read` actually returns? The file that you attempt to read, what kind of file is it? What is its content? Is it a binary file that can contain embedded zeroes? If it's a binary file then don't use text output (like `cout << output` etc). What is the purpose of the data you receive? How are you supposed to use the data?

Comment: Neither `libssh2_sftp_read` nor `memcpy` stop at `\0`, you should check `x`.

Comment: Start using `std::string` and print that out, `operator<<` for `(const) char*` will stop at `\0`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I updated to add some info of the file. `libssh2_sftp_read` will return the number of bytes he write into the buffer. the `cout` I forget to remove it! xD

Comment: @RickAstley Yap, the file have ~98kb, but the x is 30000. But the output is much smaller than that

Comment: Have you tried reading smaller chunks of data in a loop?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, and that worked!

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the code is just snippet and so the below comment may not be appropriate if there is a loop revolving around the base snippet.

The `libssh2_sftp_read()` may not read the full bytes of the file, but the maximum it can read in a single invocation. So this call may need to be repeated until either it returns zero or the scan the read buffer to check for EOF character. [EOF checking could make platform-dependent of your code]. Just highlighting the man page below.

> Reads a block of data from an LIBSSH2_SFTP_HANDLE. This method is
>   modelled after the POSIX read(2) function and uses the same calling
>   semantics. libssh2_sftp_read, will attempt to read as much as possible
>   however it may not fill all of buffer if the file pointer reaches the
>   end or if further reads would cause the socket to block.

Comment: One problem is `libssh2_sftp_read()` is returning 30000 and the output have 224 bytes.

Comment: @Samega7Cattac What does it mean *"output have 224 bytes"*? Where does your question provide this information anyway?